# Why is it wrong for "Soft questions" to be somewhat broad?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I understand the need for specificity so that SE members can answer as well as possible. I also understand that general questions may not lead to fruitful answers// answers that the OP wasn't looking for. This is extremely obvious to me in strictly math related questions.

However, I find that soft questions aren't as easy to articulate [all the time.] I've had two reference-request questions. The first of which was on "simplicial complexes" and a good explanation of them. However, the second was about a reference to help get a peer "in to" advanced mathematics.

[can be found here: [A book on advanced math for a "novice" mathematician, but "mature" thinker](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697478/a-book-on-advanced-math-for-a-novice-mathematician-but-mature-thinker])

I'm looking for a question that is indeed broad in nature, but that's because I need help to narrow it down! If I had something specific in mind for that question, I wouldn't need to ask it.

So, how can I improve the quality of these types of questions so that they meet the standards of SE, without compromising the nature of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Tags are not excuses or shields against closure. Tagging a question with [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) or [big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) does not mean the standard closing reasons don't apply to it. If it's too broad, it gets closed as such.

If you need help articulating an acceptable question, post a meta-question here:  ["how should I ask about..."](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ahow+should+I+ask)

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that. I merely meant that sometimes soft questions are somewhat broad by nature. Perhaps you are right though, and I should work on wording them